# D3 reusable chart tootip follows wrong chart when update

Tags: d3.js, charts

I created two graphs based on Mike Bostock's Towards Reusable Charts, here is the link to the visualization: http://jhjanicki.github.io/reusable-chart-tooltip/
The tooltip (the circle and vertical line for now) seems ok at first, but when you either select a dropdown item or click on a button, the line and the circle works for the graph for which you clicked or selected, but if you go to the other graph, instead of having the tooltip follow the lines on that graph, it seems to follow a different invisible line instead.  I've been stuck on this for a couple of weeks now and I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction.  Thank you very much! And here is the link to my repo: https://github.com/jhjanicki/reusable-chart-tooltip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that both graphs have same `xScale` and `yScale`

So when ever you change the data you reset the domain:

```
 xScale
.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }))
.range([0, width- margin.left - margin.right]);
```

And both the graphs are looking at the same xScale so the calculation below will fail on mouse over.

```
xScale.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]),
```

You can also understand the case that initially both the graphs are same.
So it works.
But the moment you change the data for one of the graph the xscale will differ and so the problem.

So the fix is that both graphs should have different xScale.

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback! I will edit my code today and give it a shot!

Comment: Also, do you have recommendations in terms of how to go about creating two or more xScale and yScale for reusable charts? Instead of declaring them outside the selections.each, should I declare them within it and give different names to xScale and yScale based on each graph?

Comment: I would be giving different names xScale1 and xScale2 for graph 2